# How to completely set page title and description in React.js using Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to set a page's title and description via [Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useRef } from "react";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const PageSample = (props) => {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>
                Some Title
            </title>
            <meta name="description" content="Some Description" />
        </Helmet>
    );
};

export default PageSample;
```

At here, it shows it on the page. But I recognized that, when I try to share link (whatsapp or something else) it doesn't provide this title and description of head tags.

How can I set these values?

Answer (score 0):

Try these additional tags:

```js
  const title = 'Title';
  const description = 'Description';

  return (
    <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ lang: 'en' }}>
      {/* General tags */}
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={description} />

      {/* OpenGraph tags */}
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

      {/* Twitter Card tags */}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@rbika" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
    </Helmet>
  );
```

You can find more information about these tags here: [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/), [Twitter Card Tags](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/markup).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's same

Comment: Where are you testing it? I use it this way and it works on WhatsApp

Comment: I'm testing it on WhatsApp, on app I use it in custom component

Comment: Which page do you put the Helmet?

Comment: Is the component you added Helmet present in the page of the url you are sending on WhatsApp? You can put it in the root application component like this example (https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#example).